Solving a Complicated Coupled System of ODEs
Basically the title; I've stumbled across the following complicated nonlinear ODE system in one of my research works and was wondering if an analytic solution could be achieved. Here is the system (note that the variables of interest here are $\left\{A\left(y\right), B\left(y\right), C\left(y\right)\right\}$)
\begin{align}
A_{yy}\left(y\right)-\delta\cos y + \left(\dfrac{\xi}{\lambda}\right)C_y\left(y\right) & = 0 \\
C\left(y\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}-\dfrac{2\beta}{\sqrt{\left(B\left(y\right)-1\right)^2+4C\left(y\right)^2}}\right)-A_y\left(y\right)-\nu C_{yy}\left(y\right)& = 0 \\
\left(B\left(y\right)-1\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{\lambda}-\dfrac{2\beta}{\sqrt{\left(B\left(y\right)-1\right)^2+4C\left(y\right)^2}}\right)
-2\,C\left(y\right)A_y\left(y\right)-\nu B_{yy}\left(y\right)& = 0\end{align}
where $\left\langle\cdot\right\rangle_y$ denotes a $y$-derivative and anything not written with a "$\left(y\right)$" notation is a constant. My first attempt was to try to consider polar coordinates somehow (e.g., here) and I have a nagging suspicion that this might exactly be what is required, but I couldn't get too far. Any help/insight would be appreciated!
P.S., if easier in any way, a solution to the case where $\nu = 0$ could also be useful.

First step: replace $B(y)$ with $K(y) = B(y) - 1$; that'll make it at least a little simpler.

In what sort of dynamical system did these equations arise, if you're happy to say? Partly out of curiosity and partly because that may hint at a best approach.

@Tom, these arose out of the steady-state of a fluid system I was looking at. It's a shear flow with a sinusoidal forcing (so that $A$, for example, is a velocity field). By symmetry and other arguments, everything can be reduced to one spatial coordinate, i.e., $y$. For reference, it is very much possible to obtain a solution when $\beta = 0$ (of course haha!) but I'm trying to find an extension to this (i.e., when $\beta\neq 0$ and specifically, when $\beta > 0$).

@gettingmathy I tried to use $D=B-1$ and $E=2C$, followed by a polar substitution of $D=R\text{sin}\theta, E=R\text{cos}\theta$, which removed the denominator radicals. Sadly, the slight asymmetry of no coefficient of $C$ at the start of eqaution 2 along with the double derivatives made it a bit messy. Setting $\nu=0$ helped, and gave $D$ and $E$ a direct algebraic relation of $4\lambda\beta = (E^2+D^2+1)(2-D)$, but that's as far as I got...

@gettingmathy Are you looking at the Kelvin-Helmholtz instability?

@JohnBarber, nope, this is for the steady-state solution of a 2D shear flow I'm investigating
